# DDD reusable functionality in an Entity/Aggregate

Tags: entity, aggregate, domain-driven-design, aggregate-functions

I have the following desing in DDD

- **Post** Aggregate with

  - **Body**: HTML of the post
- **Banner** entity with

  - **Html**: HTML of the banner

The **Banner** entity belongs to Post aggregate, so I want to create a method **BodyWithBanners** in the **Post** aggregate.

The point of this method will be to search into the HTML of the **Post.Body** and insert the HTML of the **Banner**.

So far, so good.

However I have intention of reuse this functionallity in abstract: "Insert some HTML inside another HTML". So I'm creating a diffent class for doing that: **BannerReplacer**

Here comes the problem, how should I invoke this new class?

- Just create an instance inside the **Post.BodyWithBanners** method (breaking Dependency Injection)
- Passing the **BannerReplacer** in the constructor of the **Post** aggregate (This can be a nightmare for creating **Post** instances)
- Passing the **BannerReplacer** to the **BodyWithBanners** method (which implies the client using **Post** must handle the **BannerReplacer**)

I have chosen for now the first option, but I don't feel really confortable with it, I believe there must be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have chosen for now the first option, but I don't feel really comfortable with it, I believe there must be a better way of doing this.

Much of the time, the first option is fine -- so you should practice being comfortable with it.  That mostly means thinking more about what dependency injection is for, and having a clear picture in your mind for whether or not those forces are at play here.

If Banner is an entity, in the `domain-driven-design` sense, then it is probably something analogous to an in memory state machine.  It's got a data structure that it manages, and some functions for changing that data structure, or answering interesting questions about that data structure, but it doesn't have I/O, database, network etc concerns.

That in turn suggests that you can run it the same way in all contexts - you don't need a bunch of substitute implementations to make it testable.  You just instantiate one and call its methods.

If it runs the same way in all contexts, then it doesn't need configurable behavior.  If you don't need to be able to configure the behavior, then you don't need dependency injection (because all copies of this entity will use (copies of) the same dependencies.

When you do have a configurable behavior, then the analysis is going to need to look at scope.  If you need to be able to change that behavior from one invocation to the next, then the caller is going to need to know about it.  If the behavior changes less frequently than that, then you can start looking into whether "constructor injection" makes sense.

You know that you intend to use a single BannerReplacer for a given method invocation, so you can immediately start with a method that looks like:

```
class Banner {
    void doTheThing(arg, bannerReplacer) {
        /* do the bannerReplacer thing */
    }
}
```

Note that this signature has no dependency at all on the *lifetime* of the bannerReplacer.  More particularly, the BannerReplacer might have a longer lifetime than Banner, or a shorter one.  We only care that the lifetime is longer than the doTheThing method.

```
class Banner {
    void doTheThing(arg) {
        this.doTheThing(arg, new BannerReplacer())
    }

    // ...
}
```

Here, the caller doesn't need to know about BannerReplacer at all; we'll use a new copy of the default implementation every time.  Caller's that care which implementation is used can pass in their own.

```
class Banner {
    bannerReplacer = new BannerReplacer()

    void doTheThing(arg) {
        this.doTheThing(arg, this.bannerReplacer)
    }

    // ...
}
```

Same idea as before; we're just using an instance of the BannerReplacer with a longer lifetime.

```
class Banner {
    Banner() {
        this(new BannerReplacer())
    }

    Banner(bannerReplacer) {
        this.bannerReplacer = bannerReplacer;
    }

    void doTheThing(arg) {
        this.doTheThing(arg, this.bannerReplacer)
    }

    // ...
}
```

Same idea as before, but now we are allowing the "injection" of a default implementation that can outlive the given instance of Banner.

In the long term, the comfort comes from doing the analysis to understand the requirements of the current problem, so that you can choose the appropriate tool.